# What privileges to grant in order to select from all PDBs

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Why both select doesnt return the same result?
Or if you want more general question - What privileges to grant in order to select from all PDBs.

```
conn / as sysdba

create user c##nir identified by c##nir container=all;

grant connect,dba,resource to c##nir container=all;
grant select on cdb_synonyms to c##nir container=all;

select CON_ID  from cdb_synonyms  group by CON_ID;

    CON_ID
----------
         1
         4
        11
        10
        14
         5
         8
        13
         3
         7
        15
         6
        12
         9

conn c##nir/c##nir

select CON_ID  from cdb_synonyms  group by CON_ID;

    CON_ID
----------
         1

select CON_ID  from containers(dba_synonyms)  group by CON_ID
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: First things first, why are you creating objects in the **container database**? You could use the **pluggable database** for you general database tasks. Also, single-tenant container i.e. one CDB-PDB doesn't need multitenant license. So, just use PDB and things won't be complicated.

Comment: The `create user` can be created inside other PDB it doesn't matter, and doesn't relate to the problem (this is just a quick demo)

Comment: I am not following you the way you are describing your problem. But, one thing is for sure, all PDB's are just like different databases for an end-user. So, whatever you used to do in pre-12c releases to access an object in a different database, you need to do the same.

Comment: I want to access all synonyms from all the CDBs by one select (no matter how many PDBs I have in each CDB)

Comment: "*I want to access all synonyms from all the CDBs by one select*" There is only one container i.e. one CDB that contains one or more PDBs.

Comment: Now i'm confused. I think my demo is very clear. I want `c##nir` to get the same result as `sys`

Comment: `SYS` is special, and it always needs `SYSDBA`. If you want another user alike `SYS` then you need to grant equal privileges of `SYS` to that user. But, beware, it is not recommended. There is no reason to give equal privileges to another user as that of SYS. Trust me as a DBA.

Comment: You are relating everything but the question itself. `SYSDBA` is not the kind of privilege I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer:

```
ALTER USER c##nir set **container_data=all** container = current;
```

CONTAINER_DATA controls the data which will be viewed from.